# Grab value from .env file with dotenv and pass them into a docker run command

Tags: docker, dotenv

I have the following .env file:

```
MY_SECRET_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello
```

I installed `dotenv` to load variables from this env file and run the docker command as follows:

```
dotenv -- docker run --name postgresql-container -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$MY_SECRET_POSTGRES_PASSWORD -d postgres
```

When I run the command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.

       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the

       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
```

However, when I just run the following command to ensure that the env is loaded, it shows up fine:

```
dotenv -- bash -c 'echo "$MY_SECRET_POSTGRES_PASSWORD"'
```

I know I can use `--env-file` to pass in the entire env file but I rather like to pick the values that I pass is so that I do not expose anything unnecessary to the container.

Comment: you obviously need to run `docker run` in the context of `dotenv`, just like you do with the `echo` command

Comment: Sorry that was an error in the example - I have fixed it now. However, that's my point - running it in the dotenv context does not give me the value.

Comment: I see the problem. I'll post the solution and explanation now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the difference in output:

```
MIHAI=test bash -c "echo Var is: $MIHAI"
```

Var is:

```
MIHAI=test bash -c 'echo Var is: $MIHAI'
```

Var is: test

The difference is the single and double quotes.

When you run this:

```
dotenv -- docker run --name postgresql-container \
  -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$MY_SECRET_POSTGRES_PASSWORD -d postgres
```

`MY_SECRET_POSTGRES_PASSWORD` gets evaluated before it is sent to `dotenv`. So dontenv does not receive a `$...` but an empty value.

Correct:

```
dotenv -- bash -c 'docker run --name postgresql-container -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$MY_SECRET_POSTGRES_PASSWORD -d postgres'
```

This way what is between the single quotes is sent as is to dotenv.

Comment: This works well, save for the extra dash in `--e`. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: you are right. sorry for that. I updated the answer